# Android Service and Activity change a value in service from an Activty

Tags: android

So i need to change an a value  of a double in a Service while its running from an activity. How can i do this?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interact with the `Service` you'll need to bind it from within the Activity instead of start it. Once you bind with the service, the Activity will have an interface through which it can call into the Service to do things like you're talking about. See the [documentation for Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for information on how to bind.